# Flutter error Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild' on "flutter run" for mobile app

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to run my project in a mobile device but I am getting this error message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\\Users\\m226349.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\androidx.annotation\\annotation-experimental\\1.3.0\\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar.
> Failed to transform 'C:\\Users\\m226349.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\androidx.annotation\\annotation-experimental\\1.3.0\\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\\Users\\m226349.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\androidx.annotation\\annotation-experimental\\1.3.0\\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar.
> Failed to transform 'C:\\Users\\m226349.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\androidx.annotation\\annotation-experimental\\1.3.0\\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I've already tried to use **flutter pub cache clean**/**flutter clean** but still. I would like to know what can I do to solve this error!